# Can't get a simple Chrome Notification to work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to bring up a simple Chrome Notification by clicking a button and for some reason I am getting an error.
Here's the Javascript part:

```
    $('#notification').click(function () {
        var opt = {
            TemplateType: "basic",
            title: "Just a test!",
            message: "Let's see if it works",
            iconUrl: "icon.png"
        }

        chrome.notifications.create('notify', opt, function () { });
});
```

The HTML part:

```
    <input id="notification" type="submit" value="Get Notification!" />
```

And the manifest:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "SimpleNotification",
"description": "Just a notification",
"version": "1.0",

"browser_action": {
    "default_icon":"icon.png",
    "default_popup":"popup.html"
},

"options_page" : "options.html",

"background": {
    "scripts" : ["eventPage.js"],
    "persistent" : false
},

"permissions" : [
    "storage",
    "notifications",
    "contextMenus"
]
```

}

When trying to run I am getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Where are you calling chrome.notifications?, This can be call only from the extension (background). You can do this, by [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to background script.

Example:

```
//contentScript.js
var opt = {
    TemplateType: "basic",
    title: "Just a test!",
    message: "Let's see if it works",
    iconUrl: "icon.png"
};
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: "shownotification", opt: opt}, function(){});

//background.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request.type === "shownotification"){
        chrome.notifications.create('notify', request.opt, function(){})
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I found that I should have run from the extension itself and not from the browser

Comment: Ok I made it work but for some strange reason I need to reload the extension to make it work again..

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently the code is correct. I was trying to run the page with Chrome instead as an extension.
Go figure...